# Send HTTP Post request with YII Framework

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, yii, http-post

There is way to send HTTP post request from my Controller?
I want to post data and results would return into JSON.
I didn't find extension and information for yii about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ehttpclient/
This is yii extension from Zend Framework

Answer (score 4):

Below code should work for you, just make sure to enable php_curl extension.

```
<?php

// URL on which we have to post data
$url = "http://localhost/tutorials/post.php";

// Any other field you might want to post
$json_data = json_encode(array("name"=>"PHP Rockstart", "age"=>29));
$post_data['json_data'] = $json_data;
$post_data['secure_hash'] = mktime();

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Set URL on which you want to post the Form and/or data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Data+Files to be posted
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
// Pass TRUE or 1 if you want to wait for and catch the response against the request made
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// For Debug mode; shows up any error encountered during the operation
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
// Execute the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Just for debug: to see response
echo $response;
```

Comment: Its hard way to do it. And its good if I don't use any framework to make HTTP Request. I want to find way I can use yii framework to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[yii-curl](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-curl/) is another extension you can use, obviously a wrapper for [PHP's cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the [curl](http://us.php.net/curl) PHP extension.